# BigQuery REGEXP_EXTRACT return null

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

from google analytics export I am trying to extract last number from the trafficSource.campaign field with next query:

```
SELECT
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(trafficSource.campaign,r':(\d+$)') as campaign,
FROM
  [95677969.ga_sessions_20160109] AS results,
WHERE
  hits.type IN ('TRANSACTION','PAGE')
```

This Query works fine in UI and the number is returned by every row match the reg expresion, but when I copy paste this query in my script allways null value is returned.

trafficSource.campaign values are like this:

```
_dfa_107202:4637224:8531522
```

Please can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you please publish your script here?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @VadimSolovey, the problem was with the regex engin, it does´nt accept re2 perl character classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping is the problem here.

When you give BigQuery something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(word, r'^\w$')
```

That will work fine in the BigQuery UI (283 is the result). But if you copy the same string into your favorite programming language, it will probably try to read the `\` as one of its escape characters, so you will have to double escape it - or figure an alternative way to feed it the string unaltered by your script interpreter.

Comment: Hi Felipe, you are right, the problem is in the regex engine and it works with `r'([[:digit:]]{3,}$)'`